# How to modify nginx configuration with ansible?

Tags: nginx, ansible

I want to add websites with SSL-certificates and URL-redirects to my running `nginx-server`. I thought of adding a config per website to `nginx/conf.d/newsite.conf` and then restarting `nginx`, but I thought maybe there is a more pretty way with `ansible`?

I think I need this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.newsite.com newsite.com;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/newsite.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/newsite.com_private_key.key;
        return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

I would like to create that conf from a remote machine with ansible uploading key&cert also.

Comment: What do you mean by "a prettier way"? It will mostly boil down to creating the config file, certificate and key and reloading all the same. The syntax will differ but the end actions will mostly be the same...

Comment: I mean is there a complete process to achieve this with ansible? Maybe what modules to use and an example? Requesting a certificate from Letsencrypt, installing it and adding a new config for nginx and the restart. Obviously it boils down to a config file and certificate&key, because that is how nginx is configured. I would be very surpprised, if the answer would be a jpeg in /var/log

Answer (score 0):

You can go the simple way:

- Using copy, making a an array var and just loop provisioning,

  ```
   files:
   - name: my_cool_config.conf
     path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
     content: |
       Hey Content here!
  ```
- or you can use template with Jinja for file templating (but i think it would be an overkill)

If you need to reload `nginx` after file provision add notify and a handler to restart/reload the service.